# How to convert type Expression to work on different type in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

How to convert `Expression<Func<A, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<B, bool>>` in C#?

The `A` and `B` can be really different classes (e.g. no common parent).

I would want to do something like: hi expression working on type `A`. The property you use from type `A` are e.g. `SomeProperty` from type `B`. So run the expression on type `B`.

I have read that I could use `ExpressionVisitor` class, but I really even don't imagine how could I use it because I don't know how it works.

This is example in code:

```
public async Task FindAsync(Expression<Func<A, bool>> where, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // _dbContext.B.Where is here for B type, like .Where<B>()
    // But the method parameter where is for type A
    return _dbContext.B.Where(where).SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

So I want run expression of type `A` on type `B`, but don't know how to convert it.

The types could looks like this:

```
public class A
{
    public string AProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string AProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string BProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string BProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

And this is example mapping between these 2 types:

```
var a = new A
{
    AProperty1 = "x",
    AProperty2 = "2"
};
var b = new B
{
    BProperty1 = a.AProperty1,
    BProperty2 = a.AProperty2
};
```

And it's result I would want to achieve:

```
Expression<Func<A, bool>> where = p => p.AProperty1 == "x" && p.AProperty2 == "2";
// Convert result will be as below:
Expression<Func<B, bool>> result = p => p.BProperty1 == "x" && p.BProperty2 == "2";
```

I hope I expressed my problem well. Please ask if you have any questions.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253323/discussion-on-question-by-szyszka947-how-to-convert-type-expression-to-work-on-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `Dictionary<string, string>` that maps all referenced properties from the original parameter type to the new parameter type:

```
var mapping = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { nameof(A.AProperty1), nameof(B.BProperty1) },
    { nameof(A.AProperty2), nameof(B.BProperty2) }
};
```

You can use an `ExpressionVisitor` subclass to replace the lambda parameter with a new parameter of the new type and all member expressions with new member expressions referencing the new parameter and the mapped replacing property:

```
var resExpr = whereExpr.ReplaceLambdaParameter<A, B>(mapping);
```

Here is the extension method and `ExpressionVisitor` subclass:

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    public static Expression<Func<T2, bool>> ReplaceLambdaParameter<T1, T2>(this Expression<Func<T1, bool>> orig, Dictionary<string, string> pMap) =>
        (Expression<Func<T2, bool>>)(new LambdaParameterReplacer<T1, T2>(pMap).Visit(orig));
}

public class LambdaParameterReplacer<T1, T2> : ExpressionVisitor {
    Dictionary<string, string> ParameterMap;
    ParameterExpression oldP, newP = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");

    public LambdaParameterReplacer(Dictionary<string, string> pMap) => ParameterMap = pMap;

    [return: NotNullIfNotNull("node")]
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node) {
        if (node is Expression<Func<T1, bool>> lambdaExpr)
            oldP = lambdaExpr.Parameters[0]; // save original parameter to replace later
        return base.Visit(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> lambdaExpr)
        => Expression.Lambda(Visit(lambdaExpr.Body), newP);

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression parmExpr) {
        if (parmExpr == oldP)
            return newP;
        else
            return base.VisitParameter(parmExpr);
    }
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression memberExpr) {
        if (memberExpr.Expression == oldP)
            return Expression.Property(newP, ParameterMap[memberExpr.Member.Name]);
        else
            return base.Visit(memberExpr);
    }
}
```